# iOS application update failed after app transfer with 'rejecting upgrade' error

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, app-id, bundle-identifier

I have my iOS app transferred from one apple account to another which causes team id change. Clean re-install works fine but every time I install an update I get the following error:

> [MIInstallableBundle performVerificationWithError:]: 517: Upgrade's
>   application-identifier entitlement string (new_teamid.bundle.id) does
>   not match installed application's application-identifier string
>   (old_teamid.bundle.id); rejecting upgrade.

I found [the solution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2319/_index.html) to update Entitlements with the 'previous-application-identifiers' key and request new provisioning profile from Apple to be able to sign the app:

```
<key>previous-application-identifiers</key>
<array>
    <string>{Your Old App ID Prefix}.YourApp.Bundle.ID</string>
</array>
```

Without that provisioning profile I get the following error during installation process:

> Failed to verify code signature of MIExecutableBundle path = path.app identifier = bundle_id type = 4 0xe8008016 (Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile)}

So I contacted Apple and requested the magical provision profile.

- Did I found the right solution to be able to update the app?
- Will Apple be able to help me and provide provision profile?
- How long could it take Apple to generate and provide the profile?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this? We have the same problem and the Apple team wont give us this magical profile.

Comment: We spent two weeks in daily communication over email, all my requests were understanded incorrectly, were addressed incorrectly or were tried to be be solved by suggest like 'use the same team id to solve the issue'. After several tries we were able to reach apple support team by phone and after short conversation we were promised not with the 'magic' profile but that they will update AppId prefix to old one and we will be able to re-generate proper profile by ourselves. Unfortunately the last task is still in progress by Apple. Waiting on them, will keep you posted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eventually we were able to get a clear response and help from Apple. It turned out that no magical profile will be provided and as instead Apple Support went to our apple developer portal and adjust `AppId` to have old `TeamId` prefix.

As a result we were able to regenerate new `Provision Profile` with old `TeamId` from our side and rebuild/resign the app. Everything continue to work as expected after that and we were able to update the app.

tip: we spent several weeks in communication over email with the apple support team and several guys from the support and "special tech team" were trying to help us. Turned out that the most efficient way is do a direct call to the Apple support (specify a case number) and solve the issue over the phone.

Comment: Same problem here; transferred two apps… Is an official apple bug right here then ?

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue and call apple. They told me it is the problem of TestFlight, and there will be no problem after you release the version update. Tasks like provisioning update will be handled during release. But I don't know it is true or not, we did not release the version update yet.

## Update

We finally use another app to test the "Transfer App" process, ignore TestFlight "rejecting upgrade" error, and proceed to submit for review. Everything is ok after released.

By the way, we also called and mailed apple every day for a week, only got so polite replies, but no any useful tip. Don't count on apple if you can test by yourself.

Comment: We check it locally, though ubertesters, tesflight and all the approaches gave us the same result. So the assumption was that it will be an issue once app is released. We didn't risk by releasing the app without fixing the issue. Otherwise all our users could get an error during the update and never get the update (without uninstallation).

Comment: Daniel did you get to try it?

Comment: It is a risk. We are still waiting for apple's advice, but no advice util now although we call apple every day.

Comment: @DanielWang did you tried to ask them to update appid prefix for specific app to the old one?

Comment: Tried to ask them to update appid prefix to the old one, but no response from apple. So we use another app to test "Transfer App" by ourselves. everything is ok after released.

Comment: "everything is ok" means you were able to UPDATE the app from appstore? I'm asking because if you delete the app from the device and then go to AppStore and do a clean installation there will be no error. The issue occurs when you are trying to UPDATE the app

Comment: Fresh Install, Upgrade from old version released by previous apple account, Push Notification, In App Purchase, we verified these points, and no error found.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing that isn't mentioned here is that this is actually known behavior by apple. They even mention it here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2319/_index.html

It can be summarized and resolved using these steps:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever receive the new provisioning profile from Apple?

Comment: @Ruenzuo Sadly no - but we ended up doing what Daniel Wang did and used another app to "simulate" the same process. We saw that the keychain remained in tact, so we went ahead and did it with the original app and it worked fine. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - we ran into the same issue and managed to get it resolved relatively quickly (< 2 days) by calling Apple Developer support and providing them the exact error message (from the iPad log) and other details (app id, etc).  We also gave them a link to this SO thread.  We are pretty happy with Apple Support's responsiveness and communication getting this done.

Comment: absolutely great, I glad it helped